# SQL-Server: Updating table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one which represents some data and one that links two pieces of data together.
The first, `Redaction`, has three columns; `ID`, `X`, `Y`.
The second, `LinkedRedactions`, has two columns; `PrimaryID`, `SecondaryID`, which are the `ID`s of two of the rows from `Redaction` that are linked, and need to have the same `X` and `Y` value.

What I want to do is update the values of `X` and `Y` in `Redaction` for the `SecondaryID`s if they are not already the same as the values for `X` and `Y` for the corresponding `PrimaryID`.

Unfortunately I cannot use a `TRIGGER` since the scripts will be running on kCura's Relativity platform, which doesn't allow them. A SQL script would be ideal, which would be run every few seconds by an agent.

I've tried declaring a temporary table and updating from that, but that gives me the error

> "must declare scalar variable @T"

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    [ID] INT, [X] INT, [Y] INT
)

INSERT INTO @T 
    SELECT 
        [ID], [X], [Y]
    FROM 
        [Redaction] AS R
    WHERE 
        [ID] IN (
            SELECT [PrimaryID] FROM [LinkedRedactions]
        )

UPDATE 
    [Redaction]
SET
    [X] = @T.[X], [Y] = @T.[Y]
WHERE
    [Redaction].[ID] IN (
        SELECT [ID] FROM @T
    )
```

*Disclaimer: This is only my second day of SQL, so more descriptive answers would be appreciated*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire code can be simplified using inner joins.

```
UPDATE red
SET [X] = redPrimary.[X], [Y] = redPrimary.[Y]
FROM [Redaction] red
INNER JOIN [LinkedRedactions] redLnk ON red.[ID] = redLnk.SecondaryIDs
INNER JOIN [Redaction] redPrimary ON redLnk.PrimaryID = redPrimary.[ID]
```

**Explanation:**

```
[Redaction] red
[LinkedRedactions] redLnk
[Redaction] redPrimary
```

red, redLnk and redPrimary are called aliases and they're used to call the table by using a different name.

```
INNER JOIN
```

This is a type of join that only matches if the same column value exists on both the left and the right table.

```
UPDATE red
--SET statement
FROM [Redaction] red
```

This updates only the [Redaction] table via it's alias 'red'.

```
INNER JOIN [LinkedRedactions] redLnk ON red.[ID] = redLnk.SecondaryIDs
```

This joins the Link table and the table to be updated by the secondary IDs and ID respectively.

```
INNER JOIN [Redaction] redPrimary ON redLnk.PrimaryID = redPrimary.[ID]
```

This joins the Link table and the [Redaction] table again but uses the Primary ID and ID columns respectively. This is a self join which allows us to update a set of values in a table with a different set of values from the same table.

No WHERE conditions are needed since the conditions are handled in the ON clauses.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Could you give a brief explanation of how it works please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE FROM`

```
UPDATE [Redaction]
SET
    [X] = T.[X], 
    [Y] = T.[Y]
FROM 
    @T T
WHERE
    [Redaction].[ID] = T.[ID]
```